# when is my Outlet bound with the IB element?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, iboutlet

I created an element using IB. Then, I link that element with the proper outlet from the ViewController.

**When is this element bound with my outlet?**

As an example:
We are using a Storyboards.
We have set the custom class for the viewController/scene to MyViewController
The outlet is an IBOutlet UILabel *

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel     * myLabel;
@end
```

We create an instance of MyViewController using

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

We present this new instance to the user.

**When does myLabel point to something valid(not nil)?**

Comment: When viewDidLoad is called

Comment: When your application is finished loading and all windows/views are set in the view hierarchy, which is finished/happening once viewDidLoad is called as @Jeff has said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IBOutlet` will be set after `loadView` is called. This is automatically called the first time you access the `view` property on your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you hooked it up correctly in your `viewController` it will be loaded when the app opens. There is no need to worry about how fast it will be loaded, as the user will not notice it.